# Upload not working with Jquery xhr & Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have image upload function in my "form" which gets uploaded via ajax. So, until image is uploading, User continues to fill rest of form. and than click on submit button which is another ajax function to submit whole form.

Problem is I have below function for image upload :-

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery(':button').click(function(){
                var formData = new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'upload.php',  //Server script to process data
                    type: 'POST',
                    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                        var myXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                        }
                        return myXhr;
                    },
                    //Ajax events
                    beforeSend: function(e) { $('#progress').css('display', 'block'); },
                    success: function(e) {
                        if (e != "no" && e != 'dir') {
                            $('#img').attr("src", e);
                            $('#imglinktosent').val(e);
                        } else if (e == 'dir') {
                            alert('Oops! We could not find \image\ directory or may be permission is not correct');
                        } else {
                            alert('File was not Uploaded, Kindly Upload Image with Size less than 512KB');
                        }
                    } ,
                    error: function(e) { alert('error' + e.message); } ,
                    data: formData,
                    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            });
            function progressHandlingFunction(e){
                if(e.lengthComputable){
                    $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
                }
            }
        });//]]>
```

It was hindering my complete form submission, therefore i changed it into Below function.

```
function uploadimage(){
            jQuery(':button').click(function(){
                var formData = jQuery('#myfile').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'upload.php',  //Server script to process data
                    type: 'POST',
                    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                        var myXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                        }
                        return myXhr;
                    },
                    //Ajax events
                    beforeSend: function(e) { $('#progress').css('display', 'block'); },
                    success: function(e) {
                        if (e != "no" && e != 'dir') {
                            $('#img').attr("src", e);
                            $('#imglinktosent').val(e);
                        } else if (e == 'dir') {
                            alert('Oops! We could not find \image\ directory or may be permission is not correct');
                        } else {
                            alert('File was not Uploaded, Kindly Upload Image with Size less than 512KB');
                        }
                    } ,
                    error: function(e) { alert('error' + e.message); } ,
                    data: formData,
                    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            });
            function progressHandlingFunction(e){
                if(e.lengthComputable){
                    $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
                }
            }
        }
```

So, that whenever user clicks on "upload image" button. Image will get uploaded by "`uploadimage()`" function set on "`button`" with event "`onclick`".

But `PHP` was giving error with "undefined index myfile" in `upload.php`

After searching for a while, i found, There was "`request payload`" and no `formdata` option in `header`.

After searching more in stackoverflow, i found i have to specify this too :

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

as if you would have noticed at line 30, I am sending direct `formData`

```
data: formData,
//Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
```

**

### But I am unsure where should i specify

**

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

in my `uploadimage()` function to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax doesn't support binary file transfers by default. I think it is more easy to base-64 encode your image and just post the data string to the server. You can use a html5 canvas element to get a base-64 encoded string from your image `canvas.toDataURL();` . Server side you'll need to decode this string with `base64_decode($yourimagedatastring);`

Comment: No, you got my point wrong. I mean Where should i add `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` in my function `uplpadimage()`.